# how can i use multiple arguments in an `os.system` or `popen`

Tags: python-3.x, windows, raspberry-pi, raspbian

So I am writing a script that will basically search google for whatever query you have.
the only problem I have is at the very end when the command is executed by `os.system()`

```py
from os import system

q = input('what is your query:')
for char in '%':
    q = q.replace(char,'%252B')
for char in '+':
    q = q.replace(char,'%')
for char in ' ':
    q = q.replace(char,'+')
```

I have tried instead of directly putting it all into `os.system()` I have tried putting it into variable `fq`

`fq = 'xdg-open https://www.google.com/search?q=', q, '&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB881GB881', sep=''`

but I get an error saying I cannot assign to a *literal*.

I have gone and looked elsewhere but it all looks way to complex for me, so if you could explain how (don't tell me exactly what to do with my script) it would be appreciated.

oh and I'm writing this on windows but is intended for use on raspbian but as far as I can tell that won't make a difference.

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Select it with the mouse and click `{}` in the formatting toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic*. Or start each line with 4 spaces. Thank you.

Comment: use `+` insted of `,`

Answer (score 0):

your system call should look like this

```
system("xdg-open https:://www.google.com/search?q={}&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB881FB881".format(q))
```